# How to allow only some IPs for the root of the website and all IPs for specific subset of URIs?

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, blacklist, whitelist

I have a website which is protected by `Allow from` IP filter but there is one specific subset of URLs which I would like to be open for everyone.

`dev.someweb.com` should be available only from specific IP addresses
`dev.someweb.com/api/v1/<anything here>` should be available to everyone and with all methods  - GET, POST etc.

Here is my current httpd.conf example:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /home/webroot/devsite/public
        ServerName   dev.someweb.com
        <Directory /home/webroot/devsite/public>
            SetEnvIf REQUEST_URI "/api/v1/" allowapi=1
            Order deny,allow
            Deny from all
            Allow from 192.168.1.0
            Allow from env=allowapi # this does not work, dev.someweb.com/api/v1/someresource still fails with 403 if accessing from another IP
            AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog /home/webroot/devsite/tmp/log/error_log
    </VirtualHost>
```

I tried moving SetEnvIf to different places - still it does not work, `dev.someweb.com/api/v1/someresource` is always forbidden outside of `192.168.1.0`

Just in case - I'm restarting Apache after all changes and I do not see any errors in its log file.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use setenv, just add a new directory allowing access

```
<Directory /home/webroot/devsite/public/api/v1/>
   Order deny,allow
   Allow from 
</Directory>
```

If it is a virtual URI path then use `<Location /api/v1/>` instead of `<Directory>`

Comment: Just tried `Location /api/v1/>Order deny,allow Allow from all</Location>` after my current `Directory` IP filter but still getting 403. The only way which works is with `SetEnvIf User-Agent MyPassThroughAgentString alloagent=1` and `Allow from allowagent`

Comment: I'm afraid you may have conflicting configuration. I've tested both `<Directory>` and `<Location>` solutions on a simple test server and both work fine. Also, explicitly clear your browser cache or user a command line tool to test